# Ubuntu 13.10 does not detect the touchpad on Samsung Ativ 8

Tags: touchpad, samsung

Just installed Ubuntu 13.10 on my Samsung Ativ 8. Unfortunately the Touchpad is not detected.

Output from `xinput list`:

```
Virtual core pointer                        id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Atmel Atmel maXTouch Digitizer            id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Microsoft Bluetooth Notebook Mouse 5000   id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ WebCam SC-10HDP12631N                     id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Anybody have an idea how this can be activated?

Answer (score 0):

I use an Samsung ATIV 8 ([Samsung ATIV Book 8 870Z5E X04](http://www.samsung.com/de/consumer/notebooks-pcs/ativ-books/ativ-book/NP870Z5E-X04DE?subsubtype=ativ-book-8)) and with ubuntu 14.04 LTE x64 Desktop my touchpad works even nicer than in Windos 7. Gestures are amazingly fluent and reliable like paning around a page up/down/diagonal with one ore two fingers.

You might want to try it with the newer ubuntu version.